# Restsharp deserialize multiple fields into same array

Tags: c#, attributes, json.net, restsharp

Does anyone know how to write a class that allow restsharp to deserialize a json that has multiple integer fields (with different names) into one same array?

I have a json

```js
{  
   "id1":"23",
   "id2":"30",
   "id3":"99"
}
```

```cs
public class Post {
  [RestSharp.Deserializers.DeserializeAsAttribute(Name = "id1")]
  [RestSharp.Deserializers.DeserializeAsAttribute(Name = "id2")]
  [RestSharp.Deserializers.DeserializeAsAttribute(Name = "id3")]
  public int[] IdArray { get; set; }
}

var res = await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);  
var list = deserial.Deserialize<List<Post>>(res);
```

It won't work, compiler does'nt allow duplicate attribute. I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve that.
Deserialize multiple int fields into an array without writing further code..

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Instead, **edit your question** and put all of the appropriate details there. Be sure to include a description of **what the code is doing** and how that differs from **what you are expecting the code to do**. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips.